# Find comments on a post on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

Tumblr posts have comments in the form of reblogs where someone else adds some message on the bottom of the reblog.

On a posts's links there's tons and tons of reblogs without additional content and likes. Clicking on "show more" shows more and more content-less links. Is there any way to find the ones with content easily?